# Trying to deploy in firebase hosting a web flutter app

Tags: firebase-hosting, flutter-web

I am trying to deploy a web flutter app in firebase hosting, but every time I have the default page that affich at the link show: https://confidentialrulesweb.firebaseapp.com I use the code below to display:

```
  firebase login
  firebase init
  flutter build web
  firebase deploy
```

thanks to show me how to deploy the right way

Answer (score 0):

How did you answer the questions when you set up your webservice?  You must specifically say "build/web" for the path.

Comment: thank you Mr, I add in firebase Init when is asked build/web but even with that and the code I enter in the question it's lead my app to the default index.html for firebase hosting. I don't know why

Comment: When you did `firebase init hosting`, did you enter `build/web`?  And was build/web already built? `flutter build web`?  And then did you `firebase deploy --only hosting`?

Comment: sorry and thank you for your answer, I am seek a litle, get better and will try again 'try it if i remember right, one time --only hosting,